# Fuelphp Stacking Login Driver Instances

Tags: authentication, fuelphp

My Auth config looks like:

```
return array(
    'driver' => array('Tokendriver', 'Apidriver'),
    'verify_multiple_logins' => true,
);
```

Both of these drivers are custom.

What is the best way to leverage `verify_multiple_logins` to let these drivers "stack" - that is, if `Tokendriver` fails, I want to try to validate using `Apidriver`.

My current method is:

```
    $auth = \Auth::instance('Tokendriver');

    if (!$auth->login())
        $auth = \Auth::instance('Apidriver');

    if ($auth->login())
    {
        // do login stuff
    }
```

but this is not optimal. I would like to be able to add more login drivers and not have to update my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In the current code base, login() is a method of the login driver, there is no global code in the Auth class that would deal with this at the moment.

Please add a feature request for this at https://github.com/fuel/auth/issues, or send a PR with an implementation.

Comment: The docs recommend using `\Auth::instance()->login()` (http://www.fuelphp.com/docs/packages/auth/examples/auth.html) which is what I'm trying to do here. Your comment makes sense but isn't really to the point; it's the `verify_multiple_logins` failover/stacking thing I'm looking for. Is there a fundamental problem with the way I'm doing it?